# Setting variables as custom field values

Tags: customization

I have a function that performs some custom queries to get specific information regarding a post (children count, dates, etc).

I am wondering if it is possible to send this custom query info (set as a variable) to a custom field automatically when I update the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Hook into the `save_post` action, then perform your custom queries upon save, and store them as custom fields of the post.

```
add_action('save_post', 'my_extra_meta_saver');
function my_extra_meta_saver($post_id)
{
    global $post;

    // Prepare whatever extra information you want here

    // Save each piece of info in a custom field
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_key', 'meta_value');
}
```

Comment: Does the add_action have to go in a plugin or can it be placed in the functions file as well, outside of the function?

Comment: It can go in `functions.php`.